# what is the meaning of "*width" property in CSS?

Tags: css

I found these lines

```
 width : 74.358974359%;

 *width: 74.30578286963829%;
```

in style sheet but i can't understand what is the meaning of `*width` ???

i searched in Google but no result found.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a [CSS hack](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/) that targets Microsoft IE 7 only.IE7 will honor that CSS rule even though it is invalid due to the asterisk. All other browsers will ignore it. So by using the asterisk you can effectively target IE7 only. This is usually done to compensate for IE7 behaving badly and rendering content incorrectly and needing a special rule to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error. It's one of the IE hacks. Internet Explorer parses CSS in a slightly different way, allowing for certain hacks that will be ignored in other browsers. You can target different versions of IE with different hacks.

So in CSS, it makes the property name invalid and stops it being parsed.

Thanks to bugs in browsers, it is sometimes ignored. This effectively causes the property to apply only to browsers featuring that particular bug — IE7.

In general, it should be avoided in favour of conditional comments.

## [Unrecommended hacks](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml)